# Posting model to controller using Ajax call and returning single variable to display success message on screen

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I am able to pass a model to my controller via an ajax call, but I am not getting the desired outcome.

Controller:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateUserDetails([Bind(Exclude = "Password, ReportPassword")]AdminViewModel model)
{
  (.... Code that does not need to be displayed ....)

   return Json(new { status = "success"}, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Ajax Call:

```
    $("#submitUserDetails").submit(function (e) {
        var userId = $("#Id").val();
        var FirstName = $("#FirstName").val();
        var LastName = $("#LastName").val();
        var ResetUserPassword = $("#ResetUserPassword").val();
        var Email = $("#Email").val();
        var selectedRole = $("input:radio[name='RolesSelectedOnView']:checked").val();

        var Model =
        {
            "Id": userId,
            "FirstName": FirstName,
            "LastName": LastName,
            "ResetUserPassword": ResetUserPassword,
            "Email": Email,
            "rolesSelectedOnView": selectedRole
        };

        $.ajax({
            url: '@Url.Action("UpdateUserDetails", "Admin")',
            data: JSON.stringify(Model),
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                if (data.status === "success") {
                    $.smallBox({
                        title: "<strong>Challenge Deleted</strong>",
                        content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i>Challenge was successfully deleted! <strong>You will now be redirected back to the My Challenges page</strong></i>",
                        color: "#659265",
                        iconSmall: "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout: 4000
                    });

                }

            }
        });

    });
```

So what I want is for the same screen to stay open, but just want the "SmallBox" to display the message, instead I am getting a blank screen jsut with this:

> {"status":"success"}

The URL also contains all the info from the model, which I also dont want.

I have even tried the following to post the form to the controller(Which also works) but im getting the exact same result!

```
    $("#submitUserDetails").submit(function (e) {
        var form = $(this);
        var url = form.attr("UpdateUserDetails", "Admin");  

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: url,
            data: JSON.stringify(form.serialize()), // serializes the form's elements.
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset-utf-8",
            success: function (data) {

                    //alert(data); // show response from the php script.
                    $.smallBox({
                        title: "<strong>User Details Saved</strong>",
                        content: "<i class='fa fa-clock-o'></i> <i> <strong></strong></i>",
                        color: "#659265",
                        iconSmall: "fa fa-check fa-2x fadeInRight animated",
                        timeout: 4000
                    });
            }
        });

        e.preventDefault(); // avoid to execute the actual submit of the form.
    });
```

All I want to do is submit the data, let the controller do what it must, and then just popup a message that it was saved successfully. What am I doing wrong ?

**EDIT**

Something to mention that could help - This is being run from a partialview

Comment: Check the network tab in dev tools to see what your response is

Comment: Response shows {"status":"success"}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a button with type="submit", I think you need to `return false` in your event handler to prevent the normal behavior.

**EDIT: (based on chat)**

The event handler is not being bound to the button since the partial view containing the button is rendered after initial page load. Solution is to move the event handler code into the partial view.

Comment: But shouldnt e.preventDefault(); be avoiding the submit of the form ?

Comment: In theory that should work. But if you're using ajax, why even use a submit button at all, why not use button type="button"?

Comment: Makes sense. Changed the type to "button" and changed the submit of the jquery to click and pointed to the button Id, now its not executing at all :( - Could it not have anything to do with the fact that the form and button are on a partial view ?

Comment: That's a sign then that your js code probably wasn't firing on the form.submit event either, which would make sense why it was continuing with a normal post. Is the partial view being rendered with the parent page, or dynamically after initial page load?

Comment: So I have an autocomplete textbox which populates user names. WHen I click on the name, it returns the partial view(which is obviously inside the view) with the users data. This partial view has the submit button in it. So I want to submit this data back to a controller and only return a json value so that I can do a popup, without having to refresh or redirect the page(i.e. the current users data must still be visible)

Comment: Heck, even if I can redirect to the view again(meaning everything is cleared), I am fine with that - Just aslong as I can use the ajax call, to allow me to popup the successful message before redirecting.

Comment: If your javascript code is being rendered in the parent view, and you have the event handler code inside document.ready, then it won't bind to the button in the partial view b/c it isn't there when the document.ready event fires. You need to bind the event handler after you render the partial view (or just move the event handler code into the partial view)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180534/discussion-between-axlewack-and-akerra).

Comment: Just to confirm - I needed to change my button type from "submit" to "button" and put the JS into my partial view and it worked(I know... not best practice) but it worked. Could you update your answer to reflect this? Thanks. and thanks for the help bud! Appreciate the patience.